# How to get reduction formula of $I_{n,-m}=\int\frac{\sin^nx}{\cos^mx}dx$?

Tags: integration

> How to get reduction formula of $$I_{n,-m}=\int\frac{\sin^nx}{\cos^mx}dx$$

---

### **My try**

### *_*

Here $s=\sin,c=\cos,t=\tan,s_0=\csc,c_0=\sec,t_0=\cot$
$$I_{n,-m}=\int s^nc^{-m}dx=\int s^{n-2}c^{2-m}(c_0^2-1)dx=\int s^{n-2}c^{2-m}(c_0^2)dx-I_{n-2,2-m}$$
Using Integration parts
$$I_{n,-m}+I_{n-2,2-m}=\int s^{n-2}c^{2-m}(c_0^2)dx\\=s^{n-2}c^{2-m}t-\int s^{n-1}c^{1-m}((n-2)s_0+(2-m)c_0)dx=?$$

---

Answer is of the form/ Spoiler:

> $$I_{n,-m}+\frac{n-1}{m-1}I_{n-2,2-m}=?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying, this problem you would have probably noticed that,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\sin^n(x)}{\cos^m(x)}  = \frac{d}{dx}( nI_{n-1,1-m} + mI_{n+1,m+1}) $$
This gives,

$$\frac{\sin^n(x)}{\cos^m(x)}  = ( nI_{n-1,1-m} + mI_{n+1,-1-m}) $$

Now, put, $n\mapsto n-1, m\mapsto m-1$.
Guess what?, The problem is solved :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but I feel that my answer is probably stupid $$I_{n,-m}=\int\frac{\sin^nx}{\cos^mx}dx=\int\frac{(1-\cos^2 x)\sin^{n-2}x}{\cos^mx}dx=I_{n-2,-m}-I_{n-2,-m+2}$$